# executing an validation(expression) on a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sympy

I have a dataframe df with 2 columns

```
Sub_marks Total_marks
40         90
60         80
100        90
0           0
```

I need to find which all rows fails the criteria that sub_marks <= Total_marks.
Currently i am using sympy function as below

```
def fn_validate(formula,**args):
    exp=sy.sympify(formula)
    exp=exp.subs(args)
    return exp
```

I am calling above function using apply method as below

```
df['val_check']=df.apply(lambda row:fn_validate('X<=Y',X=row['Sub_marks],Y=row['Total_marks']),axis=1)
```

I am expecting a column val_check with True/False expression validation result. But in case of 0 values, I am getting error.

```
Invalid Nan Comparison
```

I cant remove this values from the dataframe
Please let me know, is there anyother way to do this expression validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df['val_check'] = df.Sub_marks <= df.Total_marks                                                                                                                                    

 df                                                                                                                                                                                  

   Sub_marks  Total_marks  val_check
0         40           90       True
1         60           80       True
2        100           90      False
3          0            0       True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare columns and store them in a list.

```
condition = df['sub_marks']>=df['total_marks']

print(condition)
```

Output:

```
[True,True,False,True]
```